# Error when installing the Wikibase in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

Now I'm trying to install wikibase, I did everything as written here: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Installation#Install_dependencies.

I use the Wikibase version 1.35 as well as MediaWiki 1.35. PHP version - 7.4.13.

However, when enabling mediawiki, I get the following error:

```
MediaWiki internal error.

Original exception: [3eecb645794ad1c3e148c91b] 2021-02-04 16:25:37: Fatal exception of type "Error"

Exception caught inside exception handler.

Set $wgShowExceptionDetails = true; at the bottom of LocalSettings.php to show detailed debugging information.
```

I wrote $wgShowExceptionDetails = true;, but it didn't give anything, except for a huge incomprehensible text.

This is what I inserted at the end LocalSettings.php:

```
# Wikibase
wfLoadExtension( 'WikibaseClient', "$IP/extensions/Wikibase/extension-client.json" );
require_once "$IP/extensions/Wikibase/client/ExampleSettings.php";    
$wgWBClientSettings['repoUrl'] = 'https://pool.my.wiki';
$wgWBClientSettings['repoScriptPath'] = '';
$wgWBClientSettings['repoArticlePath'] = '/wiki/$1';
$wgWBClientSettings['repositories']['']['repoDatabase'] = 'poolwiki';
$wgWBClientSettings['repositories']['']['changesDatabase'] = 'poolwiki';
$wgWBClientSettings['siteLinkGroups'] = [ 'mywikigroup' ];
$wgWBClientSettings['siteGlobalID'] = 'en';
```

Also, I don't really understand composer and don't know what to do with installing dependencies. Similarly, I don't understand how to execute commands from the root directory of the MediaWiki installation. I think I'm wrong to have done these things. Could you describe these two points in more detail, what to write in which file and what to move where, and how to execute commands from the root directory of the MediaWiki installation, if it is not difficult for you? Thank you very much in advance.